# How to test the code coverage of a java web application in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans, code-coverage

I have a java web application and I use Netbeans6.9.1 to develop it.
I wrote some Junit test class of some DAO classes, but I failed to run code coverage test.
It seems [NetBeans Code Coverage Plugin](http://wiki.netbeans.org/CodeCoverage) does not support java web application 
code coverage,
and I can not activate coverage collection as the [Tutorial](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TutorialCodeCoveragePlugin).
Any ideas?

Comment: What makes you say it doesn't support web app code coverage?

Comment: @artbristol http://netbeans.org/features/all.html.   It says 'code Coverage for Java SE and NetBeans NBM projects'.

Comment: Are you using Maven? If yes, I have a solution...

Comment: @JVerstry no... thanks anyway

Comment: I'm having the same problem now. If I right-click a java web project, the menu item "Coverage" appears disabled =(.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing *unit* tests of DAOs, none of the code will run on the app server yet (since the DAOs should be instantiated in the same JVM as the test class), so you should be able to do code coverage. What exact errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Cobertura is a good code coverage tool, and there's a plugin for NetBeans, too.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that the [Codecoverage](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38945/unit-tests-code-coverage-plugin-updated-for-netbeans-7-0) plug-in works in Netbeans 7.2.
However in web projects the Coverage menu option is NOT active :-(